# Как проверить содержание в нескольких переменных разных слов?

Tags: php

Например, у нас есть переменная $tory, переменная $rety и переменная $wer, нужно создать условие, при котором код выполняться не будет, если $tory не содержит "привет" или "пока" и если $rety не содержит "здесь" или "там" и если $wer не содержит "fas" или "ben".

Если хотя бы одна из переменной не содержит одно из этих слов, то код не выполняется. Мой набросок:

```
if (
    $tory == "привет" ||
    $tory == "пока" ||
    $rety == "здесь" ||
    $rety == "там" ||
    $wer == "fas" ||
    $wer == "ben"
    )
{
    код
}
```

Но данный код будет работать, если хотя бы одно из условий выполняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
if (
  ( $tory == "привет" || $tory == "пока" ) &&
  ( $rety == "здесь" || $rety == "там" ) &&
  ( $wer == "fas" || $wer == "ben" )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

> код выполняться не будет, если $tory не содержит "привет" или "пока" и если $rety не содержит "здесь" или "там" и если $wer не содержит "fas" или "ben"

В вопросе содержится ответ. =)

```
if( // если
    (strpos($tory, 'привет') === false || strpos($tory, 'пока') === false) && // $tory не содержит "привет" или "пока" и
    (strpos($rety, 'здесь') === false || strpos($rety, 'там') === false) && // $rety не содержит "здесь" или "там" и
    (strpos($wer, 'fas') === false || strpos($wer, 'ben') === false) // $wer не содержит "fas" или "ben"
){} // код выполняться не будет
else{
    // код выполняется
}
```

Хотя, конечно, лучше инвертировать все условия и поменять "и" и "или" - так можно обойтись без else.

Comment: ling, зачем использовать такую сложную конструкцию, чем она лучше кода timka_s?

Comment: у меня строгое равенство, у @ling поиск подстроки

Comment: @ling, у тебя кстати логическая ошибка)))

Comment: @timka_s, я написал в лоб, ровно как в задании, чтобы показать логику. Топикстартер может написать свой вариант).

Answer (score 2):

или так, лично для меня - этот код лучше читается.

```
if (
    in_array($story, array("привет", "пока")) &&
    in_array($rety, array("здесь", "там")) &&
    in_array($rety, array("fas", "ben"))
   ) {
 ....
}
```